# Enum default methods

Tags: java, oop, types, enums, interface

I'm trying to add a default method for some of my `enums` using an interface with `default` method. The method should check if `enum` is in array(`varargs`) of `enum` values.

1. First warning I get is `"Possible heap pollution from parameterized vararg type"`, but it's not in case of `enum`, cause it's `final`, right?
2. Second warning is `"Unchecked cast: BaseEnum<E> to E"` (and `"Suspicious call"` warning witout cast). It also would be safe until I pass right type parameter when implementing my interface.
   Here is my example code:

```java
public interface BaseEnum<E extends Enum<E>> {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    default boolean in(E ... statuses){
        return Arrays.asList(statuses)
                .contains((E) this);
    }
}

public enum Transport implements BaseEnum<Transport> {
    CAR, BUS, PLANE
}

public enum Fruit implements BaseEnum<Fruit> {
    APPLE, CHERRY, LEMON
}
```

With this implementations everything looks safe. But how can I prevent something like this?(By 'prevent' I mean some code restrictions)

```java
public enum Transport implements BaseEnum<Fruit> {
    CAR, BUS, PLANE
}
```

I've looked at new `Java 15` `sealed` feature, but seems its not the case. Is there any cleaner solution?

Comment: It's not possible

Answer (score 6):

There is no need to create an interface for such an operation. The [`EnumSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/EnumSet.html) class serves this purpose:

```
Fruit fruit = ...;
boolean match = EnumSet.of(Fruit.APPLE, Fruit.CHERRY).contains(fruit);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But when I compare this approaches, second looks clearer:
1) `boolean match = EnumSet.of(Fruit.APPLE, Fruit.CHERRY).contains(fruit);`
2) `boolean match = fruit.in(Fruit.APPLE, Fruit.CHERRY);`

Comment: @AndreiYusupau I don't think you can make it type safe using your approach. Your interface may be implemented by a regular class rather than an enum. One thing to note is that you don't really need the cast in the `contains()` method, you can just do `.contains(this);`.

Comment: If it happens so that this won't be of type `T` without cast it would just silently return `false`, but with cast it would be an `ClassCastException`.